# differentiating two routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 routes as

```
get '/v1/cameras/:id' => 'cameras#single', as: :cameras_single
```

and the another one is

```
get "v1/cameras/map" => "cameras#map"
```

Both are getting disturbed as if I am putting `cameras/map`, It goes to `camera/:id` as an parameter, Is there any way to differentiate them?
any help will be thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `get "v1/cameras/map" => "cameras#map"` above `get '/v1/cameras/:id' => 'cameras#single', as: :cameras_single` in `routes.rb` file.

Routes file is scanned from top to bottom and the first matching route is taken.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have tried this but its giving me an error on `cameras_single` at controller.. as ` <% @cameras.each do |camera| %>` `undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: nope its not its going on camera's single template. but I have method def map in cameras controller as well

Comment: Thanks it working I am having another issue right now.

Comment: Please post it as a separate question and drop the link here I will try to address the same.

Answer (score 0):

The rails routes file is searched and matched from top to bottom, they basically are the same url, both are using get and the path are the same in the real sense, `"v1/cameras/map"` will always match `'/v1/cameras/:id` by just assuming that the `:id` parameter is `map`. you can let the first path comes first, so `v1/cameras/map` will always hit first then any other path `/v1/cameras/:id` will not match the first one except when `:id = "maps"`. if its possible that `:id` can equal `map`, then the best thing is just to change the url, maybe by adding a new character or so.